# A chain of conversions JS code isn't working

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS and the task that comes with solution says we can create a chain like this:

```
let b = Boolean( BigInt(Number("1234")));
console.log('${b} [${typeof b}]');

// or

let s = "1234";
let n = Number(s);
let bi = BigInt(n);
let b = Boolean(bi);
console.log('${b} [${typeof b}]');
```

Output should come with a "True Boolean" but both learning platform and Chrome console says:

> ${b} [${typeof b}]

Am i wrong about this code? I don't know also what is the point of [] surroundings in second interpolation on both notations. Thank you for you reading this.

Comment: You're using the wrong quote characters.

Comment: The `[` and `]` don't mean anything special. They're just there as normal characters so that when the output is logged the type appears in square brackets

Comment: @Pointy i should notice that. Thanks.